# Page creator with live demo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, materialize

I'm working on a `feature` to allow members on a site to create pages that have a bunch of different templated 'cards' which can be put on each page as well as other styling mechanics using divs.

Currently there is a `static control panel` through which the sections can be added to the page using jquery/js but so far I haven't developed a functionality to save it. I need it to be saved as a `php` file as pages are included from a master page. Right now I am thinking about to build an array of objects containing the information - the user put in and posting it to a `php` file to decipher and write the file. is this the best method to implement the feature?

Comment: I recommend you to use DRUPAL CMS `drupal.org` kind of already existing applications for such kind of needs.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do this is by storing each part of the 'cards' in a database. For example; store each individual part of the card in a database and assign it to the user by setting a column in the row equal to the users id/email/username.

Pull the values from the database and echo out the variables where you'd like them on the card.